# How to format ruby exception with backtrace into a string

Tags: ruby

I have an exception `e`, and I would like to transform it into a string which is **exactly the same** as the **standard ruby output** on the `stderr` when the exception is uncaught.

Initial code gives me incorrect order of the stacktrace, and indentation is not correct.

Rather than writing my own code, I'd like to see some "oneliner". How do you do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This will be the same.

```
puts "#{$@.first}: #{$!.message} (#{$!.class})", $@.drop(1).map{|s| "\t#{s}"}
```

Or, using `e`:

```
puts "#{e.backtrace.first}: #{e.message} (#{e.class})", e.backtrace.drop(1).map{|s| "\t#{s}"}
```

Comment: Excellent one-liner, gives the exactly same output. Thanks again :-D

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing this was not possible before Ruby 2, but this is now a function in core:

```
e.full_message
```

If you don't want color codes in the output:

```
e.full_message(highlight: false)
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Exception.html#method-i-full_message

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log as a single string, not just output, you can do like this:

```rb
puts "#{e.backtrace.first}: #{e.message} (#{e.class})\n\t" + e.backtrace.join("\n\t")
```